# Fastest way to split a list into a minimum amount of sets, enumerating all possible solutions

Tags: python, list, algorithm, set, subset

Say I have a list of numbers with duplicants.

```
import random
lst = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9]
random.shuffle(lst)
```

I want to split the list into a minimum amount of sub"set"s with all unique numbers, **without discarding any numbers**. I managed to write the following code, but I feel like this is hard-coded, so there should be faster and more general solutions.

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(lst)
maxcount = counter.most_common(1)[0][1]
res = []
while maxcount > 0:
    res.append(set(x for x in lst if counter[x] >= maxcount))
    maxcount -= 1
assert len([x for st in res for x in st]) == len(lst)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{4}, {8, 2, 4}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}]
```

Obviously, this is only one of the solutions. Another solution could be

```
[{4, 9}, {8, 2, 4}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]
```

I want to find all possible solutions with minimum amount of sub"set"s (4 in this case). Note that same numbers are indistinguishable, e.g. `[{1}, {1, 2}]` is the same solution as `[{1, 2}, {1}]` for a list of `[1, 2, 1]`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why isn't `[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}]` a solution? I can't find anything in what you wrote that accounts for why the result has to contain 4 sets.

Comment: I said **without discarding any numbers**

Comment: Do you actually need to enumerate all possible solutions (as the title says), or is the count of the number of possible solutions sufficient?

Comment: @BuddyBob Actually not roasted.  The sentence is ambiguous.  "Any numbers" could be "discard no unique numbers (digits)" or it could mean "every member of the original list must be in exactly one of the result sets."  That precision in English expression makes all the difference.  Further, as TimPeters mentions, there is no explicit requirement to result in four sets.

Comment: I want all possible solutions, and this is the hardest part.

Comment: @TomServo I'm sorry I'm not a native English speaker. But I definitely know ```set(lst) = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}```

Comment: @TomServo What is so ambiguous??? I said it very clear in the title that I want to "**split** a list", not reduce a list!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This way takes time linear in the number of list elements, and its output is the same (same sets, in the same order) regardless of the input list's order. It's basically a more "eager" variation of your code:

```py
    def split(xs):
        from collections import defaultdict
        x2count = defaultdict(int)
        result = []
        for x in xs:
            x2count[x] += 1
            count = x2count[x]
            if count > len(result):
                result.append(set())
            result[count - 1].add(x)
        return result
```

Then, e.g.,

```py
    xs = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9]
    import random
    random.shuffle(xs)
    print(split(xs))
```

displays

```
[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
```

Finding all answers is bound to be annoying ;-) But straightforward enough. Once you know there are 4 sets in the result, then you have a hairy kind of Cartesian product to compute. You know that, e.g., 7 appears twice, so there are `comb(4, 2) == 6` ways to pick the two result sets 7 goes in. For *each* of those ways, you know, e.g., that 8 appears 3 times, so there are `comb(4, 3) == 4` ways to pick the three results sets 8 goes in. Now we're up to 6 * 4 = 24 partial results. Repeat similarly for all other original integers. `itertools.combinations()` can be used to do the choosing.

Unclear: consider input `[1, 1, 2]`. The output here is `[{1, 2}, {1}]`. Do you, or do you not, consider that to be the same as `[{1}, {1, 2}]`? That is, do you consider an output to be a sequence of sets (in which case they're different), or as a set of sets (in which case they're the same)? A straightforward Cartesian product takes the "it's a sequence" view.

### Finding all of 'em

Here's a way. As sketched, it computes a Cartesian product of all ways of distributing each element across the number of required output sets. But rather than use `itertools.product()` for this, it does it recursively, one element at a time. This allows it to check partial results so far for isomorphism, and decline to extend any partial solution that's isomorphic to a partial solution it already extended.

Toward that end, it views a partial solution as a set of sets. For technical reasons, Python requires using a `frozenset` for a set that'a going to be used in turn as a set element.

Caution: this generator yields the *same* `result` object every time. That's for efficiency. If you don't like that, you could, e.g., replace

```py
            yield result
```

with

```py
            yield result[:]
```

instead.

EDIT: note that I replaced the line

```
            sig = frozenset(map(frozenset, result))
```

with

```
            sig = frozenset(Counter(map(frozenset, result)).items())
```

That's because you really aren't viewing the result as a set of sets, but as a multiset of sets (a given set can appear more than once in a result, and the number of times it appears is significant). In fancier test cases than were given here, that can make a real difference.

A `Counter` is the closest thing Python has to a builtin multiset type, but there is no "frozen" `Counter` workalike akin to frozensets. So instead we turn the `Counter` into a sequence of 2-tuples, and put those tuples into a frozenset. By using `(set, count)` pairs, this allows us to account for that the number of times a set appears in a result is significant.

```py
def allsplit(xs):
    from collections import Counter
    from itertools import combinations
    c = Counter(xs)
    n = max(c.values())
    result = [set() for i in range(n)]
    pairs = list(c.items())
    pin = len(pairs)

    def inner(pi):
        if pi >= pin:
            yield result
            return
        elt, count = pairs[pi]
        seen = set()
        for ixs in combinations(range(n), count):
            for i in ixs:
                result[i].add(elt)
            sig = frozenset(Counter(map(frozenset, result)).items())
            if sig not in seen:
                yield from inner(pi + 1)
                seen.add(sig)
            for i in ixs:
                result[i].remove(elt)

    return inner(0)
```

Example:

```py
>>> for x in allsplit([1, 1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 4]):
...     print(x)
    
[{1, 2, 3, 4, 8}, {1, 4}]
[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {8, 1, 4}]
[{1, 2, 4, 8}, {1, 3, 4}]
[{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 8}]
```

For your original example, it finds 36992 unique ways to partition the input.

Comment: Yes you are right. I should make this clear. I updated the question. Same numbers are the same, regardless of their order in the list.

Comment: I wonder if these might be the building blocks for computing the derangements of the (multi)set of items https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6662

Comment: @smichr. I expect that problem would be better approached by looking at algorithms for efficient enumeration of the perfect matchings in a bipartite graph (one set of nodes corresponding to members of the multiset, the other set corresponding to ordinal positions in the derangement, and a node in one set is connected to a node in the other if and only if it's allowable for the multiset member to end up at the given position).

Comment: Thanks @TimPeters. If you had signed it nodes-are-in-orderly-yours I don't think it would have been a better confirmation of your identity :-)

Comment: Haha ;-) BTW, on second thought, algorithms for finding a perfect bipartite matching could be useful for finding _a_ multiset derangement (or determining whether a partial derangement can be extended to a full one), but I don't, after all, see a clear way to use them for enumerating. If, e.g., there are `k` instances of element `x`, a straightforward enumeration would yield `k!` permutations of those elements.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using a prefilled list then store each value in separate buckets

```
import random
from collections import Counter

lst = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9]
random.shuffle(lst)

c = Counter(lst)
maxcount = c.most_common(1)[0][1]
result = [set() for _ in range(maxcount)]
for k, v in c.items():
    for i in range(v):
        result[i].add(k)

print(result)
```

Can also be achieved with a `defaultdict`

```
c = Counter(lst)
result = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in c.items():
    for i in range(v):
        result[i].add(k)
result = list(result.values())
print(result)
```

---

Note on performance

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np
lst = list(np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000))
nb = 1000
print(timeit(lambda: prefilled_list(lst), number=nb))   # 2.144
print(timeit(lambda: default_dict_set(lst), number=nb)) # 1.903
print(timeit(lambda: op_while_loop(lst), number=nb))    # 318.2
```

Comment: Just testing your first answer: it only finds one solution, whereas OP wants all of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

My simple solution, returning sets from biggest to smallest:

```
# Problem definition
import random
lst = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9]
random.shuffle(lst)

# Divide in sets, biggest first
l = lst.copy()
sets = []
while l:
    sets.append(set(l))
    for item in sets[-1]:
        l.remove(item)
```

Now the hard part, combinations. I suggest starting from something similar and expanding, what follows is just a proof of concept and avoiding duplication other than the trivial "move the entire difference set across" is not covered. The real implementation will cover all combinations of set -> set transfers (just add another itertools.combinations level) but I have no idea how to handle moving element from and to different sets in parallel in a clever way off the top of my head.

```
import itertools
more_sets = [sets]
diff_0_1 = sets[0] - sets[1]
for comb_size in range(1, len(diff_0_1)):
    for comb in itertools.combinations(diff_0_1, comb_size):
        s0 = sets[0] - set(comb)
        s1 = sets[1] | set(comb)
        more_sets.append([s0, s1] + sets[2:])

for some_sets in more_sets:
    print(some_sets)
```

The above code returns this:

```
~ python3.8 tmp.py
[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {8, 2, 4}, {4}]
```